# Doctrine2/DBAL + Postgresql - public. schema missing in Doctrine queries | Empty query's result

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, postgresql-9.6, dbal

on my VPS server queires Doctrine's query responsible for counting executed migrations returns no rows. Problem is weird, using PHPStorm sometimes I also got no results but it happens only when I skip **public**. schema. I can't set in Doctrine's config table name with public. prefix due to further DBAL problems. Localy I got same version of PgSQL 9.6 and PHP 5.6, onle difference @VPS is PHP 7.1.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user", public'    # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''          # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
```

Changing search_path helps partialy, it sometimes causes rows to appear as query's result however Doctrine migration still has problem with it.

Queries:

```
SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions;  --  sometimes no results, even if ros actually exists
SELECT * FROM public.doctrine_migration_versions;   --  works always
```

Thanks in advance for any answears.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem was that database user was the same as existing schema. That's why Postgres by default was looking for user named schema and it found it. Changing postgres conf to do not look for user but public. schema only, solved 'problem'

```
#search_path = '"$user", public'    # schema names
```

to

```
search_path = 'public'    # schema names
```